# PhD Admissions - Does it matter if I work in the same lab for 4 years?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, research-undergraduate

I started working in a lab on campus as a freshman and I really like what we are doing and in a perfect world I would be more than happy to stay here for my remaining time.

But, since I want to get my PhD (in a field that is related but not necessarily the same to the work I do in the lab) would it be more beneficial to leave this lab and join another one at one point? Obviously it is not ideal for personal reasons (because I really enjoy it a lot), but for professional reasons and applications reasons I can see the benefits to having multiple experiences before applying.

Comment: no, it doesn't matter

Comment: @Our would you mind explaining why just so I can understand a little better?

Comment: if you explain why you think it might matter, then I'll explain why it doesn't

Comment: @Our I think it would matter because I feel like a number of various different experiences in research as opposed to 1 experience would look better since it would show more experience and make it seem like I am flexible and enjoy research. I feel like phd programs may be more hesitant if their program doesn't align with what Im doing they might think Im not interested (obviously this is assuming I write a good personal statement as well).

Comment: an experience is an experience, regardless of in which institution it was done. They care about what you can say & offer as a researcher & academics; #institutions you have visited in your limited academics career is not one of them (as long as all of these institutions are credible ones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna disagree with a previous responder. When it comes to demonstrating fit with a lab you want to join for a PhD, not all prior research experiences are created equal. How beneficial it would be to change labs will depend on how close your potential graduate school work is to your current work (both in terms of field and in terms of research methods). If the labs you'll be applying to are studying similar topics and/or using similar methods, then not much is gained by changing labs.

Once you have any research experience, the fit of your experience to future lab becomes the next most important part of evaluating, and diversity of lab experiences for diversity's sake isn't terribly helpful. If changing labs will get you experience that is more relevant to your grad school goals, then you might strongly consider it.

PS Having 4 years of research experience and a good letter of rec from your supervisor is plenty to show that you enjoy research; you don't need to diversify your experiences for that reason.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate this answer a lot! This makes a lot of sense to me and I think I will stick with my lab since it has a lot to do with what I want to go into.